# Scala shorthand $ for converting string to column does not recognize string variable

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to use the $ shorthand with Spark applications written in Scala. But I have a large number of columns which I would like to reference using variables. At the same time, I want to use the $ shorthand notation for strings which hold the column name.

```
df.select($"col1") // works
val columnName = "col1"
df.select($columnName) // gives error
```

How do I use the variable columnName with the $ shorthand?

Comment: the only workaround which I have is to use df.select($""+columnName)

Comment: use `col(columnName)`

Comment: The `$` is a macro that only work with literal values.

Comment: @Lamanus that ends up being `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` not `org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks, is there a macro which works with variables?

Comment: @Ash a **macro** executes at compile-time, it can't work with variables.

Answer (score 5):

What you might want is.

```scala
val columnName = $"col1"
df.select(columnName)
```

`$` is shortcut for `new ColumnName("name")`

Answer (score 2):

Noone mentioned one quite important thing - `$` is an implicit `StringToColumn` conversion.

Have you imported `spark.implicits._`, where `spark` is your `SparkSession` object?

That should solve your problems :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `col` function.

```
df.select($"col1") 
val columnName = col("col1")
df.select(columnName)
```